# How many mythic kills are needed to get mythic Iron Fleet Treasure Chest

Tags: world-of-warcraft

When having a level 2 shipyard, it generates me a raid mission which rewards me with [Iron Fleet Treasure Chest](http://www.wowhead.com/item=127855/iron-fleet-treasure-chest). This chest contains loot from the current raid tier. The quality of the loot depends on how many bosse I have already killed in the current raid tier.

How many mythic bosses do I have to kill in order to get a treasure chest which contains mythic loot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How many mythic bosses do I have to kill in order to get a treasure chest which contains mythic loot?

[You need to kill 8 mythic bosses](http://www.wowhead.com/item=127855/iron-fleet-treasure-chest#comments)